# Lazily asking for Location Services

Tags: iphone, ios, location

As soon as I install and launch my app for the first time, it immediately asks for location services, even though startUpdatingLocation hasn't been called.  I haven't even allocated a CLLocationManager instance at that point.  I'd like this prompt to be done lazily after I actually make the call so the user doesn't blindly turn it off.  Has this flow changed with iOS recently?  I remember it used to be lazily asked.  I'm using 5.1 firmware.

Comment: Are you talking about that dialog (app *** wants to use...) that shows up the first time user launches your app?

Comment: Yes indeed, it does that for some reason in 5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats interesting. I tested your hypothesis, that the location manager isn't even allocated and yet the iOS Location Permission dialogue comes up. I tried the following troubleshooting. After every step I ran the project on a device and I could only get the location popup to appear at the last step.

- Start a new app
- require location-services in info.plist
- require gps in info.plist
- link CoreLocation to the project
- Import Core Location into header
- Make and synthesise a property for a location manager
- ask CLLocationManager for +authorizationStatus
- ask CLLocationManager for +locationServicesEnabled
- alloc init a CLLocationManager instance
- tell CLLocationManager to start updating location.

Only the final step brought up a prompt.
To be sure i even created a viewController that pushed a second view controller that initialised a CLLocationManager and started updating the location. The permission popup only came up when the second view controller was pushed. This is all with the latest Xcode running on 5.1.

I have shown that location services still only asks for permission at the exact moment you try and turn locations on like it has done in previous SDKs. Perhaps check your code, maybe paste some here so we can go into more detail. :)

Comment: I'll try this too just to make sure.  All my location handling is done through a singleton, so I only have one call to startUpdatingLocation in my entire app.  I have a breakpoint on it and it never gets called.  The only other possibility I can think of is that one of the dependent frameworks, for whatever reason, is triggering this.  My project is big, so it will be a *pain* to recreate the project file.  Also I've been using and upgrading the project file since iOS 3.0.

Comment: Do you use an ad network or a telemetry framework perhaps? Head to the breakpoints sidebar, click the plus at the bottom and in the Symbol box type `-[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]` and it should break for startUpdatingLocation across your whole project and libraries. Might also be worth listening for `–startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

Comment: Thank you for this, that's a good trick to know!  It was because I was allocating (not showing) an MKMapView in the background on startup for later display.

Comment: I think if UIBackgroundModes (info.plist) contains "location" the popup will appear on app start also.